# mongodb c++ driver- error: "mongo::client" has not been declared

Tags: c++, mongodb

-compiled and installed successfully mongo-cxx-driver (mongo db c++ driver - 26Compat - all test ok passed). directory /usr, so /usrmongo/client/dbclient.h exists.

-running cmd:

```
g++ tutorial.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -o tutorial
```

-file tutorial.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h" // for the driver

void run() {
  mongo::DBClientConnection c;
  c.connect("localhost");
}

int main() {
    mongo::client::initialize();
    try {
        run();
        std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
    } catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
        std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

results - error:

```
tutorial.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tutorial.cpp:11:12: error: ‘mongo::client’ has not been declared
```

any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this helps but I got a similar error after installing the mongo-dev package using apt-get. This should not be done after mongo 2.6; it only works up to mongo 2.4 or something. It ended up corrupting my 2.6, so I had to clean up everything, reinstall mongo and then build mongo-cxx-driver from the github repo https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver according to their instructions.

Afterward eclipse still gave an error for the tutorial, but strangely it did build the thing. I had to clean up both Debug and Release there and ended up with only a warning, because the includes were messed up. So finally I just scrapped the eclipse project, copied the tutorial file to a new project and now it builds clean.